# Are these tables in 3rd Normal form?

Tags: database, database-normalization

users

| id | first_name | last_name | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | john.doe@john.doe.com |
| 2 | Mary | Doe | mary.doe@mary.doe.com |

user_details

| id | user_id | ethnicity_id | education_id | location_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Mary | 4 | 3 | 2 |

locations

| id | location | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | London, UK | 53.2321 | -1.2321 |
| 2 | Berlin, Germany | 52.2321 | -1.5345 |

Comment: no user_id and firstname are identical, resplace them with the id and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if the user_id takes the correct id values from the users table would it be in the 3rd normal form after ?

Comment: Question to ask yourself is what happens if you have two Johns? The data in `user_details` would be impossible to distingush. Ask yourself should `user_id` be the PK from `users`.

Comment: to know this we would need to understand the cardinality between each of the elements.  Based on your data No'  as users & user_details appear to have a 1:1 relationship.  so why is a separate entity needed?  Additionally if ethnicity & education can change based on location then I'm ok with them being in the user details.  If however they do not change based on a location/user, then it seems those values would make more sense in the users table.  the user_details appears to be an associative table between locations & users, and as such data on that table should be specific to that association

Comment: @xQbert What I am trying to build is like a dating app, so a user can pick their own ethnicity, education and location. Do you think is a good idea to move user_id and ethnicity_id back in the users table but keep the locations table as the lat and long actually depends on the location ?

Comment: again it depends on cardinality.  Can a user be in two locations at the same time?  Can they have more than 1 ethnicity or 1 education at the same time?   If the relationship from a user to the relative data (ethnicity, education, location) is more than 1 to 1; then a different entity is required to maintain 3rd normal form.    So if John had 2 ethnicity's then no, they have to be in a separate table.  However, if john can only have 1 ethnicity; then to me it makes sense that it would reside on the user table.

Comment: I'd even say location can be on the user record and you have no need thus far for a user details table.  and just need users/locations so far.  If we progress to 4th & 5th normal form you may want to separate out the Details table so null values are not represented in your users table if a user doensn't need to provide ethnicity, location or education.  But you asked about 3rd.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks a lot, now it makes sense when I think about the carnality

Comment: @alexB rippo also made a  great point in that the FK on user_Detials must be the PK of the user table.  otherwise a "name change" causes you to maintain data in two places; when you should only have to do it in one.  as to why 1:1 vs 1:M matter... if you have a 1:M on the same table; you end up having to REPEAT values which violates 3rd normal form.  and your KEY then also repeats or the non-repeating value must become part of the key.  so if data respective to other data in the table isn't 1:1; you need a new table.

Comment: @xQbert I understand and exactly ethnicity, education and even location is not actually compulsory so I expect to have null values. So eventually a user_details table is needed from what I understand.

Comment: only if you want to get to 4th/5th normal form.  the lack of data isn't a problem addressed in 3rd normal form. it does potentially bloat your files a bit which is why it works for 3rd normal form but not 4th/5th. but for the purposes of performance having all of them in teh same table provided the cardinality is 1:1 can be acceptable in design.  (This is an art AND a science)  your User_Dettail can become a key-value-pair concept if the details could vary from one user to another.  This gets a little ugly in the presentation layer but is a common practice.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks a lot again this really helped me a lot

Comment: Right now you are effectively asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you show no research or other effort. [ask] [Help] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the 1st place you are stuck/unsure. Quote definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you rely on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.